# Div quebrando quando conteúdo de label é muito grande

Tags: html, css, aplicação-web, div

A **div** de uma página **HTML** esta quebrando quando o tamanho do texto de uma das label que tenho dentro dela é muito grande, estou utilizando o seguinte código:

```html
<div class="divRelato" style="background-color: #eee">
  <label>Detalhes físicos Detalhes físicosDetalhes físicosDetalhes físicosDetalhes físicosDetalhes físicosDetalhes físicosDetalhes físicosDetalhes físicos</label>
  <label class="lblHoraImpacto" style="float: right;color:#999;margin-right: 0px">12-12-2016 13:30</label><br>
</div>
```

O resultado com o label com pouco conteúdo é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já a label com conteúdo grande  quebra, retornando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredito que quando o segundo label (data e hora) é "jogado" para próxima linha, a div deveria expandir junto. Esse comportamento não acontece com uso de parágrafos.

Comment: Estou longe do PC,  porém pesquise em CSS sobre nobr.

Comment: Tem algum css aplicado a div? Se sim poste-o por favor

Comment: @Leandro J. S. Paiva Já tentou criar uma "Table" dentro da div ?

Comment: Importa o bootstrap e usa o grid system. https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Comment: Altere o código acima, que simule o problema. O Atual não acontece. E por acaso tem outra `div` por fora, cada mensagem fica dentro `div``divRelato` ?

Comment: usa flexbox para ajustar a hora ao final da div e deixar o comportamento como se fosse tabela

Comment: Ta, e qual é a dúvida?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No html adiciona uma div auxiliar para o container dos blocos e usa flex-box como avia dito, segue abaixo o resultado

```
      <div class="divRelato" style="background-color: #eee">
        <div class="cntAuxiliar">
            <label class="pr">Detalhes físicos Detalhes físicosDetalhes físicosDetalhes físicosDetalhes físicosDetalhes físicosDet</label>
            <label class="lblHoraImpacto" style="color:#999;">12-12-2016 13:30</label>
        </div>
     </div>
```

CSS

```
        div.divRelato{
      display:flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    div.divRelato > label.lblHoraImpacto{
      display: flex;
      min-width: 250px;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    div.cntAuxiliar {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }
    div.cntAuxiliar{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    div.cntAuxiliar > label.pr {
      display:flex;
      flex-grow: 1;
    }
    div.cntAuxiliar > label.lblHoraImpacto {
      display:flex;
      flex-grow: 1;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      width: 200px;
      align-items: center;
    }
```

resultado

https://jsfiddle.net/zhho36v0/3/